# How did the damage output of Tristana change in 4.18?

Tags: league-of-legends

[From the 4.18 patchnotes:](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-418-notes#patch-tristana)

> General
> ATTACK SPEED PER LEVEL +4% per level ⇒ +2.5% per level
>
> Q - Rapid Fire
>
> DURATION: 5 seconds (was 7 seconds)
>
> BONUS ATTACK SPEED 30/50/70/90/110% attack speed (was 30/45/60/75/90%)

How did the damage output change? Is it more or less?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

4% per level would give 72% at level 18.
2.5% per level gives 45% at level 18.

Rapid Fire at rank 5 now gives 110% instead of 90% - so an increase of 20%

Since speed bonuses are added together then this is a total loss of 27% at level 18, however at mid levels this will not be so bad since rapid fire is usually maxed before level 18.

Note that this doesn't actually mean 25% less damage, since bonus attack speed will almost always be higher than this.

For example BOTRK + Phantom Dancer gives 40+50 = 90 attack speed. Level gives 45 and RF gives 110.

This gives a total of 90+45+110 = 235.

Previously you would have 90+72+90 for 252.

In actual % terms that's a drop of about 8%.

Looking at mid levels:
With rapid fire 5 and level 12 you get 12*2.5+110 = 30+110 = 140
Previously you got 90+12*4 = 138

So at level 12 you are actually slightly stronger than you used to be (for the first 5 seconds, after that you are weaker), but you then gain more slowly towards level 18 and never quite reach that peak hyper-carry point that you used to.

Comment: wow.... thats more than i thought. and you will probablly get less hits of in a real teamfight with the lower duration. but overall i think the changes are good: stronger mid game, weaker lategame.

Comment: Honestly I think the duration drop as well was a bit much, but we'll see.

Comment: Also the increased strength mid game is marginal to say the least, you are only a very tiny amount stronger and only for 5 seconds instead of 7.

Comment: 4% per level gives 68% not 72%. See [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_speed)

Comment: Great info. Do remember that all these calculation only apply if you use the full duration of the speed boost. Often i find myself only getting in a few (trade) hits before backing off and if that is less or equal to 5 seconds, then this change is a slight buff. It's only when you go 8 or more seconds, the last 3 seconds is decreased damage... Overall i'd still call it a nerf, but not in every situation...

Comment: @HojouHuman It's a nerf even during the 5 seconds. Her base rate of fire has dropped so as soon as you are greater than level 12 then even with rapid fire active you are doing less damage. At level 18 with those items and rapid fire active you are doing 8% less damage, even during the 5 seconds of rapid fire you still have. You are then significantly weaker while rapid fire is on cooldown.

Comment: @TimB right i see the base per level was nerfed. Guess arguing that leveling q first might outdamage at a certain level is pretty theoretical and therefore lame. So OK, you're right :)

Comment: @HojouHuman Yep, leveling rapid fire first can get you a slight power increase for 5 seconds at level 9->12 but you start falling off after that and you are always weaker outside the 5 second window.

Answer (score 3):

**[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qplFNznuClidT_sEGzRxSyTb8-VaghYzCrqEV_9YpMY/edit?usp=sharing) is the full sheet**

Even with the increase of the attack speed you will do less damage because  the duration is a lot shorter.

Note that this is without items.

I calculated everything, in the image below you can see the amount of attack speed per level without and with the ability activated.

You can also see how much attacks you will fire in 7 seconds.
[image]

Comment: note that the base AS per level also changed.

Comment: This answer also doesn't account for the extra attacks in 2 seconds without q activated - so it's overstating the effects.

Comment: @PhilippSander see edit, I added more details

Comment: @TimB see edits, I added more details

Comment: good work, but what does ap mean? i hope not ability power

Comment: @PhilippSander Sorry, that's derping, should've been as(attack speed)

Comment: then why are numbers in both charts equal? 1,025

Comment: @PhilippSander changed it, even bigger change then I thought...

Comment: Are you combining them multiplicatively? I think you're using completely the wrong formulas here but you've not posted the sheet so I can't see for sure.

Comment: could you upload and link the sheets somehow?

Comment: I uploaded the link

Comment: there are miscalculation. please take a look at this link to see how the attack speed is calculated http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_speed

Comment: feel free to join our chat to discuss it further: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift